# Can subscribers who put on notification bell see my comments on other vids of other people?

Tags: youtube

Can people who turn on notifications on your YouTube channel see comments you post on other videos?

Answer (score 1):

See? Yes.

Get notifications about where you comment? No. If you want to post text updates to your subscribers, use the [community tab](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7124474) (if available).